# @Transactional Not working with multiple repository calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions

I have a code snippet that looks like this one

**Service with @Transactional method**

```
public class XService {
    private Repo1 repo1;
    private Repo2 repo2;
    private Repo3 repo3;

    XService(Repo1 repo1, Repo2 repo2, Repo3 repo3) {
        this.repo1 = repo1;
        this.repo2 = repo2;
        this.repo3 = repo3;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public SomeObject method(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
        repo1.method1();
        repo2.method2();
        repo3.method3(); // probability of exception here, in which case rollback is needed
    }
}
```

**Class from where method is invoked**

```
public class YService {
    private XService xService;
  
    public YService(XService xService) {
        this.xService = xService;
    }
  
    public SomeObject method(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2) {
        xService.method(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

I have also added the @EnableTransactionManagement on my SpringBootApplication class. But the database operations from repo1 and repo2 are not rolled back in case of Exception from repo3.
Every repository is using Spring JDBCTemplate for querying the database.

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        // setting config properties here
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public Repo1 repo1(JDBCTemplate template) {
      return new Repo1(template);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public Repo2 repo2(JDBCTemplate template) {
      return new Repo2(template);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public Repo3 repo3(JDBCTemplate template) {
      return new Repo3(template);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public XService XService(Repo1 repo1, Repo2 repo2, Repo3 repo3) {
      return new XService(repo1, repo2, repo3);
    }

    @Bean
    @Inject
    public YService YService(XService xService) {
      return new YService(xService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those repositories are connected to different databases or same database? Can you add your `datasource` configuration and transaction manager configurations?

Comment: These are connected to the same `datasource`. I have created beans for both `datasource` and `transactionManager` in a `@Configuration` file. Added configs

Comment: Show the class where you're invoking `method`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have edited the question statement accordingly. Please have a look.

Comment: (Side note: `@Inject` is meaningless on `@Bean` methods. Spring already understands that it needs to provide the beans in the method parameters.)

Comment: Does `XService` implement any interfaces, or is it simply a class type? (That is, can Spring put in an interface-based decorator before it injects into `YService`, or does it have to use the actual instance?)

Comment: No, the services are not implementing any interfaces. They are simple class types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a TransactionTemplate and enclosing my repo calls in the template worked.

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) throws TransactionException {
          repo1.method1();
          repo2.method2();
          repo3.method3();
        }
      });
```

I don't know the reason this one worked. It will be great if anyone can help in understanding the reason behind this.